# Custom Error Handling in Wordpress Plugins

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, error-handling

I'm creating a public use Wordpress plugin and working on general error handling/logging. I've struggled to find any sort of "best practices" when it comes to Wordpress plugins.

In the realm of regular PHP, it seems [good practice](http://www.sitepoint.com/error-handling-in-php/) to set your `error_reporting`, create a custom error handler using `set_error_handler` and then `trigger_error` to capture/log details about an error. Is this a BAD idea in Wordpress plugins?

In the large number of plugins I've looked at, it seems no one is using this practice, which is why I wonder. Do setting custom handlers like this interfere with other plugins or something? Is there a better way to handle/log errors in a Wordpress plugin?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In WordPress, you would use the `WP_Error` class to handle errors.

There are a set of constants that will determine if errors are reported, displayed or logged, that you would usually define on the `wp-config.php`:

```
define('WP_DEBUG', true);
define('WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', false);
define('WP_DEBUG_LOG', true);
define('SAVEQUERIES', true);
```

Of course, when developing, you should have `WP_DEBUG` as `true`, and set it to `false` on a production enviroment.

Check the [Developer](https://wordpress.org/plugins/developer/) and [Debug Bar](https://wordpress.org/plugins/debug-bar/) plugins, and the [WordPress Error Handling](http://code.tutsplus.com/series/wordpress-error-handling--cms-657) series of articles for more info

Comment: Thanks for the help, and especially those plugins! I had read over WP_Error previously but wrote it off as being just an error container and too basic. Looking at it again, I can see how it can be extended and lead to some good practices.

How about handling the unexpected in Wordpress? In my hunting, I haven't found a WP equivalent to `set_error_handler` or `set_exception_handler`. Are those safe to use in a plugin or is there a reason I don't see other WP developers using them?

Thanks again!